# Using one function for multiple html classes in javascript (expanding text via read more button)

Tags: javascript, html, dom, getelementsbyclassname

First post on stack overflow:)

I'm trying to put one certain function on all of my HTML-buttons, so far I haven't found anything that worked after 2 days of trying out(new to coding).

What I'm basically trying to do is a 'read more' button that displays a text on click. Neither .getElementsByClassName nor .querySelectorAll have worked so far. If I use my code with just an #id it works fine, but I know there must be a better way of using one function for multiple elements instead of having multiple ids and using the function for each id individually . I've also tried a forEach() loop but it didn't do anything. Additionally I've tried `readMoreBtn[length].addEventListener('click', () => {})`, but that also didn't work.

As I said, it works with the `.getElementById` and `querySelector`, but not with `.getElementsByClassName` or `.querySelectorAll`. If I use `querySelectorAll`, the first button works but the others don't.

Since I'm interested in making it work with classes and not ids, I've removed the id-attributes from the HTML.

I won't post my full HTML since it's quite long but the container with the button looks like the following:

```
<div class="main-container">
       
        
        <h6 class="main-artist"><em class="main-emph">content</em>content</h6>
        
        <p class="main-p"><span class="moreText"> Lorem ipsum </span></p>
            <button class="readMore">read more</button>
    </div>
```

And JS:

```
const readMoreBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('.readMore');
const text = document.querySelector('.main-p');

readMoreBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  text.classList.toggle('show-more');
  if(readMoreBtn.innerHTML === "read more") {
    readMoreBtn.innerHTML = "read less"
  } else {
    readMoreBtn.innerHTML = "read more"
  }
})
```

Thank you for your help and if you have any suggestions of how to improve my way of asking questions, shoot.

EDIT: I have multiple buttons, and all of them have a unique text. My goal is it to have the buttons display their unique text below them somehow. Here's another HTML to show what I mean:

```
<div class="main-container">


        <h6 class="main-artist"><em class="main-emph">content</em>content</h6>

        <p class="main-p"><span class="moreText"> Lorem ipsum </span></p>
            <button class="readMore">read more</button>
    </div> 

<div class="main-container">


        <h6 class="main-artist"><em class="main-emph">content</em>content</h6>

        <p class="main-p"><span class="moreText"> Messi GOAT </span></p>
            <button class="readMore">read more</button>
    </div> 

<div class="main-container">


        <h6 class="main-artist"><em class="main-emph">content</em>content</h6>

        <p class="main-p"><span class="moreText"> Ipsum Lorem </span></p>
            <button class="readMore">read more</button>
    </div>
```

With this JS Code I'm able to expand the first `main-p` only, but not the others.

```
const yourFunction = (e)=>{


  const text = document.querySelector('.main-p');
  text.classList.toggle('show-more');
  if(e.target.innerHTML === "read more") {
    e.target.innerHTML = "read less"
  } else {
    e.target.innerHTML = "read more"
  }


}
```

In my head there are two solutions that might work:

1. I would have to connect each `button` to their `main-p` somehow in HTML? I've tried it but it didn't work.
2. Working with loops in JS.

Is one of those two possible? TIA

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this.
Try this one.

```js
const yourFunction = (e) => {

  const text = document.querySelector('.main-p');
  text.classList.toggle('show-more');
  if (e.target.innerHTML === "read more") {
    e.target.innerHTML = "read less"
  } else {
    e.target.innerHTML = "read more"
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">

  <h6 class="main-artist"><em class="main-emph">content</em>content</h6>

  <p class="main-p"><span class="moreText"> Lorem ipsum </span></p>
  <button class="readMore" onclick="yourFunction(event)">read more</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).

And [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).

By contrast [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) return a DOM [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element).

Each of these types are accessed and manipulated differently. You are treating the HTMLCollection and the NodeList as an Element.

One way to access every item in an HTMLCollection and NodeList is to first convert them to an array using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), then use [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) on the resulting array to iterate each Element, in this case adding a click event handler to the element:

```js
const readMoreBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('readMore');
const text = document.querySelectorAll('.main-p');
console.log(Array.from(text));

Array.from(readMoreBtn).forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('click', ({target}) => {
    target.textContent = ('read more' === target.textContent) ? 'read less' : 'read more';
  });
});
```

```html
<p class="main-p"><span class="moreText"> Lorem ipsum 1</span></p>
<button class="readMore">read more</button>
<p class="main-p"><span class="moreText"> Lorem ipsum 2</span></p>
<button class="readMore">read more</button>
<p class="main-p"><span class="moreText"> Lorem ipsum 3</span></p>
<button class="readMore">read more</button>
```

Comment: Sometimes, I want to use jQuery because of this :)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use **less JS**, but more CSS. (more flexible)

Example, just add `.is-acitve` in container (parent) so just styling in CSS

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.main-container .readMore');

const setContainerActive = (el) => {
  el.target.closest('.main-container').classList.toggle('is-active')
}

Array.from(buttons).forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener('click', setContainerActive)
});
```

```css
.main-container {
   /* Defaults */
}
.main-container.is-active {
  /* Active */
  background: red;
}
/* Example */
.main-container .show-is-active { display:none; }
.main-container.is-active .show-is-active { display: block; }
.main-container .hide-is-active { display:block; }
.main-container.is-active .show-hide-active { display: none; }
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
   <h6 class="main-artist"><em class="main-emph">content</em>content</h6>
   <p class="main-p"><span class="moreText"> Lorem ipsum </span></p>
   <button class="readMore"><span class="show-is-active">read less</span><span class="show-hide-active">read more</span></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="main-container">
      <h6 class="main-artist">
        <em class="main-emph">content</em> content
      </h6>
      <p class="main-p">
        <span class="moreText"> Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora aliquid at, provident molestiae necessitatibus ullam culpa debitis, dolorum quas accusamus quidem iusto eaque omnis veniam. Delectus quo saepe enim voluptatum! </span>
      </p>
      <button class="readmore">Read more</button>
    </div> 
    
    <div class="main-container">
      <h6 class="main-artist">
        <em class="main-emph">content</em>content
      </h6>
      <p class="main-p">
        <span class="moreText"> Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora aliquid at, provident molestiae necessitatibus ullam culpa debitis! </span>
      </p>
      <button class="readmore">Read more</button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="main-container">
      <h6 class="main-artist">
        <em class="main-emph">content</em>content
      </h6>
      <p class="main-p">
        <span class="moreText"> Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora aliquid at, provident molestiae necessitatibus ullam culpa debitis, dolorum quas accusamus quidem iusto eaque omnis veniam. Delectus quo saepe enim voluptatum! </span>
      </p>
      <button class="readmore">Read more</button>
    </div>
```

JS File locations:
If your js file is in the `<head></head>` you must have it wait for the document to load or the `document.querySelectAll();` will not work if the js file is executed before the document is fully loaded. You will get a console error. Defer the js file in the head

```
<head>
  <script src="your-js-file-name.js" defer></script>
</head>
```

or place js file at the end of the document before the `</body>` close tag.

```
<body>


<scrpit src="your-js-file-name.js"></script>
</body>
```

JS:

```
let btn = document.querySelectorAll('.readmore');
let mainText = document.querySelectorAll('.main-p');
let container = document.querySelectorAll('.main-container');
// console.log(btn);
// console.log(mainText);
// console.log(container);

btn.forEach((i) => {
   i.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
      // console.log(evt.target.previousElementSibling);
      let moreContent = evt.target.previousElementSibling;
      let button = evt.target;
      // console.log(button);
      // console.log(moreContent);
      if (moreContent.style.visibility != 'visible') {
         console.log("Style not present. Running code block below");
         moreContent.style.visibility = 'visible';
         evt.target.innerHTML = 'Read less';
      } else {
         console.log('Style present. Removing and replacing with default style  with code block below');
         moreContent.style.visibility = 'hidden';
         evt.target.innerHTML = 'Read mess';
      }
   })
});
```

CSS:
The `visibility: hidden;` will still allow the element to take up the space it occupies in the document. If this is not ideal then switch the css and js to use `display: none;` and `display: block;`. Other ways to approach it as well if a smooth transition is needed on the `.main-p` element.

```
.main-container {
   border-bottom: 1.5px solid blue;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.main-p {
   color: white;
   background-color: #333;
   padding: 15px;
   visibility: hidden; 
 }
```

```js
 
let btn = document.querySelectorAll('.readmore');
let mainText = document.querySelectorAll('.main-p');
let container = document.querySelectorAll('.main-container');
// console.log(btn);
// console.log(mainText);
// console.log(container);

btn.forEach((i) => {
   i.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
      // console.log(evt.target.previousElementSibling);
      let moreContent = evt.target.previousElementSibling;
      let button = evt.target;
      // console.log(button);
      // console.log(moreContent);
      if (moreContent.style.visibility != 'visible') {
         console.log("Style not present. Running code block below");
         moreContent.style.visibility = 'visible';
         evt.target.innerHTML = 'Read less';
      } else {
         console.log('Style present. Removing and replacing with default style  with code block below');
         moreContent.style.visibility = 'hidden';
         evt.target.innerHTML = 'Read more';
      }
   })
});
```

```css
.main-container {
   border-bottom: 1.5px solid blue;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.main-p {
   color: white;
   background-color: #333;
   padding: 15px;
   visibility: hidden;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   <script src="app.js" defer></script>
   <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   
   <div class="main-container">
      <h6 class="main-artist">
        <em class="main-emph">content</em> content
      </h6>
      <p class="main-p">
        <span class="moreText"> Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora aliquid at, provident molestiae necessitatibus ullam culpa debitis, dolorum quas accusamus quidem iusto eaque omnis veniam. Delectus quo saepe enim voluptatum! </span>
      </p>
      <button class="readmore">read more</button>
    </div> 
    
    <div class="main-container">
      <h6 class="main-artist">
        <em class="main-emph">content</em>content
      </h6>
      <p class="main-p">
        <span class="moreText"> Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora aliquid at, provident molestiae necessitatibus ullam culpa debitis! </span>
      </p>
      <button class="readmore">read more</button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="main-container">
      <h6 class="main-artist">
        <em class="main-emph">content</em>content
      </h6>
      <p class="main-p">
        <span class="moreText"> Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora aliquid at, provident molestiae necessitatibus ullam culpa debitis, dolorum quas accusamus quidem iusto eaque omnis veniam. Delectus quo saepe enim voluptatum! </span>
      </p>
      <button class="readmore">read more</button>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps you out and anyone else having a similar problem to solve. :)